# Exporting declarations for library with multiple entry points

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm exporting a library with a file structure like

```
|__ src
| |__ index.ts
| |__ other-file.ts
```

And I'd like to consume it like

```
import { something } from 'library'
import { other } from 'library/other-file'
```

How should I structure the output in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I structure the output in order to achieve that?

```
|__ lib
| |__ index.js
| |__ index.d.ts
| |__ other-file.js
| |__ other-file.d.ts
|__ src
| |__ index.ts
| |__ other-file.ts
```

With `tsconfig.json` having `outDir:lib`/ `declaration:true`/ `include:['src']`.

Use will look like:

```
import { something } from 'library'
import { other } from 'library/lib/other-file'
```

## More

- [Example Project](https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle)
- [Library authoring guide](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html)

Comment: So, even if `main` in `package.json` is pointed at `lib/index.js`, "folder paths" are relative to the root package folder? Thats something from node module resolution I have actually never noticed until now.